# .htaccess - rewrite user login in url

Tags: zend-framework, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to rewrite URL with user login and i use Zend Framework.
.htaccess of ZF project are follow:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L] 

RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

How to add rule, with rewrite

```
http://yourdomain.com/user/TOMMY
```

to

```
http://yourdomain.com/user/?login=TOMMY
```

? Where "TOMMY" is user login.

Important: after rewriting,  URL in browser leaves without changes.

I can add next rule:

```
RewriteRule ^user/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /user/?login=$1 [L,R]
```

But its not correctly, because server redirect browser to other page. 
Tnx.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the other rule so that it doesn't rewrite URI's that start with "/user/"

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/user/
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Now you can rewrite the /user requests using your rule:

```
RewriteRule ^user/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /user/?login=$1 [L]
```

Except you don't want that `R` in the brackets, because it will redirect the browser and change what's in the address bar.